# Query to produce the fault log for different devices from a table in which devices input their status with a timestamp

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, database

I have a table in which different devices log their status with a timestamp as shown in the bellow table. (status value is either ‘ok’ or ‘fault)
Note: There are no rules on when they insert their status update on the table. For example, two or three records with alert may come after each other.

[image]

I am trying to get a sql query that can produce the following result. Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Is it `MySQL` or `SQL Server` ?

Comment: thanks for the question, sql-server is better but mysql is also ok. Im more after an approach.

Answer (score 0):

this is a classic island and gap problem. Search for it and you will find lots of reference on this

```
select  DeviceID, 
    [Fault Start]   = min(DateTime),
    [Fault End]     = max(DateTime),
    [Total Fault Time] = convert(varchar(8), 
                                 dateadd(second, 
                                         datediff(second, 
                                                  min(DateTime), 
                                                  max(DateTime)), 
                                         0), 
                                 108),
    [Message]   = max(Message)
from
(
    select  *,
        grp = ID - row_number() over (order by Status, ID)
    from    your_log_table
) d
where   Status  = 'Fault'
group by DeviceID, grp
```